# Getting a syntax error from the 'Stripe.php' file

Tags: php, stripe-payments

After successfully testing the Stripe Checkout in localhost, I uploaded the pertinent files to my web hosting site, but am now encountering this error as soon as I enter it's 'home' page:

Line 204:

```
self::$appInfo = self::$appInfo ?: [];
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /.../Stripe.php on line 204

The website is up to date regarding the SSL and my web hosting service is Web Hosting Hub. I have also not modified anything from the Stripe.php file that is included in the library.

Is it not as cut-and-dry to set up the live version of Stripe Checkout as I thought after doing some local testing?

Comment: What version of php is running on the server? Looks like a version that doesn't understand `[]` is an array.

Comment: [As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with \[\]](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: can you share line 204 with us?

Comment: @emix there is no need to be unpleasant

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca The server is on version 7.0. However, when I created the phpinfo file in my domain, it appeared as 5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments say.

Since [PHP 5.4,](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) you can use the short version on an array `[]`
As per [Stripe's official PHP github repository](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php#requirements), the minimum requirement is PHP 5.4.

If you have commandline access to your server you can use `php -v` to find out the version of your php.
If not, you can upload a file with this inside:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

When you visit that file in your web browser it will tell you the version of your PHP.
For example:
[image]